# Twitter Bootstrap - Can't get form to display properly

Tags: css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, user-registration

I have a form that I'm making in bootstrap but no matter what I do, I cant seem to get it to look how it looks in the tutorials. The label goes above the text box when it should be beside it, and the whole thing looks like it lacks any css formatting. Thanks for your help.

Here is the site that I'm working on and you can view the source code there:

aerofied.snbw.co/registration.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrap.min.js returns a 404 error and I believe this is the reason.

This is the URL that returns the error: http://aerofied.snbw.co/js/bootstrap.min.js

You should also read the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms). You must use some specific classes for your forms.

Comment: do you really think that missing a js file would effect the form styling?

Comment: @Sachin Yes. Just because it's a JS file doesn't mean it hasn't got any impact on the code. For example, you should look at the document after JS did it's work while using jQuery Mobile.

Comment: It's because he's not using any of the built in [form classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for bootstrap 3.

Comment: @Sachin that still doesnt work after I referenced the file correctly.

Comment: @Adrift can you explain what you mean by form classes? I'm still super new with bootstrap obviously

Comment: @user2774108 for example you have this line: <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
You have to add form-control to that class. It will now look like this: 
<input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">